How to remap the tab key?
(I'm on Neovide)
In insert mode I want to remap tab to <c-t>. In my init.lua, I tried vim.keymap.set({'i'}, "<tab>", "<c-T>"), and the command :lua vim.keymap.set({'i'}, "<tab>", "<c-T>") but neither worked.

Could you tell us what is the result of imap <Tab>?

I you have nvim-cmp installed it overrides the Tab mapping in insert mode every time you switch to insert mode.
I suppose it is impossible to override the Tab mapping of nvim-cmp.

that’s… a choice…
